# How can I connect my silverlight application with SQL server 2005

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, silverlight, wcf-data-services

I am trying to connect my silverlight application with Sql server 2005 for login purpose. I am totally new to silverlight and want to build my own website in Silverlight. Please suggest useful sites for referance. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Constructive criticism: this question is too generic to get useful answers. The fundamental principle is that Silverlight can't connect directly to a db, so you'll need to proxy the request through something else. A very generic starting point: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=624

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Web Service example WCF. 
1)**Add a WCF to your project.**

```
//This is your interface Class.
 namespace SilverlightApplication1.Web
 {      
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService1
  {
    [OperationContract]
    bool UserLogin(string email, string password);
  }
 }

 //This is your service code behind class
 namespace SilverlightApplication1.Web
 {   
  public class Service1 : IService1
  {
    public bool UserLogin(string email,string password)
    {
                // Your logic here to verify user name and password
    }
  }
 }

 //After creating the service. Add a reference to your application.**
```

2) **Add the Service Reference to your Silverlight application.**
Right click on your project, Select the web references option and add the service to your project. Now if you have a button control on your form which will submit the data to your wcf service. Add the following code in its click event.

```
 Service1Client proxy ; 
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        proxy.UserLogin += new EventHandler<InsertDataCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_UserLogin);
        proxy.UserLogin(txtEmail.Text, "Password");
    }

   void proxy_UserLogin(object sender, InsertDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == true)
        {
            lblMesg.Content = "User Login successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMesg.Content = "User record not found";
        }
    }
```

In the button Click event call that service.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37522/7-Simple-Steps-to-Connect-SQL-Server-using-WCF-fro

Answer (score 0):

If you want a SQL Server connection for logging on, you can create a Silverlight Business Application project. It has user logon built in. This way, you can concentrate on the rest of your Silverlight application's features.